# ¿Qué son los punteros exactamente en C?

Tags: c, punteros

Tengo una gran duda y es: **¿Qué son y para que sirven los punteros?**, puesto que he estado aprendiendo Java en la universidad, pero ahora estamos dando lo básico de C. Pero no me ha quedado claro el tema de los punteros.

Me gustaría que alguien me lo aclarase, y con pequeños ejemplos si es posible.

Muchas gracias de antemano , y saludos!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Un apuntador es un objeto que 'apunta' a otra variable, normalmente usando la dirección de la misma. En C, de forma similar a otros lenguajes imperativos, usted puede declarar y definir una variable en instrucciones como estas:

```
int edad = 3;
double peso = 4.4;
```

Al ejecutarse el programa, el sistema operativo le otorga una región de memoria apropiada para almacenar el código del programa en ejecución, así como una región de datos para almacenar el contenido de las variables que el programa use y otras regiones que el programa usará para su correcta ejecución. En el ejemplo anterior, en esa región de datos estarán ubicadas las variables edad y peso.

[image: Variables del programa]

Usted como programador no tiene control sobre los lugares de memoria donde estas variables se crean, esto depende tanto del sistema operativo, como de la implementación del compilador. La imagen anterior muestra una posible asignación: la variable edad se encuentra en la dirección de memoria número 1000 y contiene el valor 3, la variable peso se encuentra en la dirección de memoria número 1004 y contiene el valor 4.4. El nombre de las variables no se muestran en la gráfica porque al ejecutarse estas pierden su significado: a muy bajo nivel no hay nombres de variables, sino direcciones de memoria, todas las operaciones que usted haga con estas variables a nivel de hardware son operaciones que se hacen modificando los valores de las direcciones de memoria, si en su programa la siguiente instrucción es:

```
edad = edad + 1
```

el compilador traduce esta instrucción de la siguiente forma:

1. Busque en la región de datos del programa la dirección de la variable edad.
2. Obtenga el valor que tenga esa dirección de memoria.
3. A ese valor súmele 1.
4. Guarde en la dirección de memoria de la variable edad ese resultado.

Por lo tanto, el resultado es que en la dirección de memoria 1000 el contenido ya no es 3 sino 4. Con lo anterior trato de explicar que a bajo nivel la máquina no entiende nombres de variables sino direcciones de memoria y operaciones que se hacen a esas direcciones de memoria. El nombre de las variables sólo es útil para el programador, precisamente para abstraer estos detalles que son dependientes del sistema operativo y el compilador.

Aquí entran a jugar las variables conocidas como apuntadores, un apuntador es una variable que almacena la dirección de memoria de otra variable. En C, usted declara un apuntador de esta forma:

```
int* apuntadorEdad;
```

La anterior instrucción indica que declara un apuntador (por el asterisco) a una variable de tipo entera (int) que se llama apuntadorEdad, como esta también es una variable, tendrá una dirección de memoria en la región de datos:

[image: Apuntador]

La anterior imagen muestra que está ubicada en la dirección de memoria 1008, como mencioné, el contenido de esta variable es la dirección de memoria de otra variable de tipo entero, como quiero guardar la dirección de la variable edad (que sólo la sabré en tiempo de ejecución), le indico la siguiente instrucción:

```
apuntadorEdad = &edad;
```

El operador & en C devuelve la dirección de memoria donde la variable está ubicada. Por lo tanto, el contenido de la región de datos es ahora:

[image: Apuntador]

Veamos qué pasó: declaré una variable llamada edad y la dirección de memoria de esta variable es 1000, porque así lo decidió el sistema operativo. Cree al mismo tiempo una variable apuntador llamada apuntadorEdad donde guardaré la dirección de memoria de la variable edad, es decir, el valor de apuntadorEdad será 1000.

Una vez realizado esto puedo modificar el contenido de la variable edad 
usando el apuntador, porque ya sé su dirección de memoria. Realizo esto usando el operador de desreferencia * en C:

```
*apuntadorEdad = 8;
```

La anterior instrucción es equivalente a "busque la dirección de memoria que almacena la variable apuntadorEdad y asígnele el valor 8". Por lo tanto, verá que la variable almacena la dirección de memoria 1000, luego irá a la dirección de memoria 1000 y el valor antiguo (3) lo cambiará a 8.

[image: Apuntador]

Los apuntadores se utilizan como forma indirecta de manipular el contenido de otras variables. La pregunta natural es ¿por qué no manipular directamente la variable en vez de crear un apuntador? es decir ¿qué ventaja hay en hacer esto

```
int valor = 123; //Supongamos que tiene dirección de memoria 1000
int* apuntadorValor = &valor; //Ahora el contenido de apuntadorValor es 1000
*apuntadorValor = 456; //Ahora el contenido de valor es 456
```

que en cambiar directamente el valor?

```
valor = 456;
```

La respuesta está en el mismo origen de C. C puede considerarse un lenguaje de alto nivel, por cuanto es una abstracción mayor que un lenguaje ensamblador, pero también un lenguaje de mediano nivel por cuanto ofrece en su misma sintaxis la opción de evadir la abstracción de forma cercana. C fue diseñado con el objetivo de ofrecer una sintaxis más cercana al programador que el lenguaje ensamblador pero sin abandonar la posibilidad de manipular directamente las direcciones de memoria. Esto es así porque fue diseñado para crear sistemas operativos. Manipular arreglos y estructuras de datos más complicadas que sólo variables primitivas (como enteros, floats...) es mucho más sencillo haciendo uso de apuntadores que de las mismas variables. Pasar apuntadores como parámetros a funciones es mucho más sencillo y rápido que pasar variables, porque en las primeras sólo pasamos direcciones de memoria mientras en la segunda pasamos la copia absoluta de la variable. Hay muchas más razones para usar apuntadores para manipular variables, que puede encontrar en el [libro](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_lenguaje_de_programaci%C3%B3n_C) de referencia por excelencia del lenguaje C.

**¿Hay apuntadores en Java?**

En sentido estricto, sí: en Java usted tiene dos tipos de variables, variables primitivas (como int, double, boolean) y variables de referencia, o cualquier tipo de dato definido por el usuario e instanciado a través del operador new. Pero, a diferencia de C, en Java no puedo usar aritmética de apuntadores. En C la aritmética de apuntadores consiste en  realizar operaciones de 'suma' o 'resta' de direcciones de memoria, por ejemplo: obtener la dirección de memoria de la variable edad, sumarle 4 a la dirección y en esa dirección resultante almacenar el valor 8. No lo permite por dos razones: primero porque la máquina virtual de Java se encarga de esto de forma absolutamente transparente al programador y segundo porque en el diseño del lenguaje consideraron que era innecesario e inseguro, y es que en realidad, en C, el manejo de apuntadores de forma irresponsable genera muchos dolores de cabeza. Haciendo aritmética de apuntadores podría acceder a direcciones de memoria a las cuales el programa no tiene permisos de acceso y corromper datos que el sistema operativo requiere. Las variables de referencia en Java en realidad son un alias a regiones de memoria donde se almacenan las propiedades de los objetos, de forma similar a C, cuya representación exacta depende de la máquina virtual de Java utilizada.

Comment: Es una respuesta bastante completa , muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 2):

El puntero es básicamente una variable que almacena una dirección de memoria. Y el contenido de esta dirección va a depender del tipo de puntero. Por ejemplo:

> int * pVar;

lo que estoy haciendo es diciéndole que el puntero va a contener la dirección de memoria de una variable entera. Creo haber sido claro, sino trato de explicarte de otra manera.