# C - duda conversión punteros void

Tags: c, conversión-de-tipos

Al convertir puntero void a string (array) si pongo asterisco previo al paréntesis más externo da error en tiempo de ejecución.

Es decir, esto no da errores:

```
printf("%s", ((char *)p));
```

Pero esto sí:

```
printf("%s", *((char *)p));
```

Además, esto otro tampoco da errores, tanto con el asterisco como sin él:

```
printf("%d", *((int *)p));
```

y si paso un array de enteros con el asterisco previo, muestra el primer elemento.
PERO, si se lo quito como hago con el string muestra 2686764.

La cuestion:

¿Qué es ese número? ¿Algo que ver con la memoria?
¿Y porqué para un tipo vale una cosa y para otro la otra?
Quisiera saber la razón que hay detrás para comprender mejor.
muchas gracias!

Comment: Se te ha olvidado una cosa: **poner un ejemplo** de *pasar un array de enteros con y sin el asterisco*.

Comment: Falta saber qué es `p`.

Comment: p = puntero, el ejemplo creí que no era necesario

Comment: printf("%d", *((int *)p));   //el que funciona

Comment: En ese caso te muestra los primeros cuatro bytes a partir de "p" como un "int".

Answer (score 2):

Hay bastante tela que cortar en tu pregunta. Quizás antes de leer lo que sigue te interese ver otras respuestas para entender mejor los punteros, como:

- [¿Qué son los punteros exactamente en C?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8362/qu%c3%a9-son-los-punteros-exactamente-en-c)
- [¿Por qué se habla de dirección de memoria cuando se trata de punteros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/144381/7123)

### Primero ¿por qué no rompe este caso?

```
printf("%d", *((int *)p));
```

`p` es un puntero a `void`, pero a menos que hayas hecho `p=NULL` (lo que inicializaría ese puntero con cero), estará apuntando a algún sitio. *Incluso si no lo has inicializado* (pero en este caso estaría apuntando a una dirección aleatoria).

Supongamos que, debido a una casualidad muy impobable, la dirección a la que apunta resulta que es una de la que puedes leer. Las probabilidades de esto son bajas si `p` tiene un valor al azar, pero es perfectamente posible si `p` está apuntando a otra variable de tu programa o si apunta a una dirección obtenida con `malloc()`.

Supongamos además que, en la dirección a la que apunta `p`, hay cuatro bytes de valor `2c`, `ff`, `28` y `00` respectivamente, los cuatro en hexadecimal (estos números no los he puesto al azar, luego veremos por qué).

Pues bien, `(int *)p` indica al compilador que, en esta expresión solamente, considere que `p` es un puntero a `int`. Al añadir un `*` delante para tener `*(int*)p` lo que estamos diciendo es "obtén el valor del entero apuntado por `p`".

Ya que un `int` en C ocupa 4 bytes, la instrucción `*(int*)p` leerá cuatro bytes de memoria. Encontrará los `2c`, `ff`, `28` y `00` que antes hemos supuesto. Si está ejecutándose en una arquitectura intel o compatible, que es *little endian*, los cuatro bytes leídos se ordenan "al revés" para crear el entero `0x0028ff2c` (hexadecimal), y ese es el valor que finalmente se le pasa como segundo parámetro a `printf()`.

Ya que en `printf()` has usado la cadena de formato `"%d"`, mostrará ese número en decimal, y resulta que es 2686764.

Por eso ha funcionado, y lo que ves es el resultado de leer 4 bytes consecutivos de memoria, de la dirección apuntada por `p` y considerarlos como un entero.

### Segundo ¿por qué sigue funcionando si quito el asterisco?

Es decir:

```
printf("%d", ((int *)p));
```

En este caso lo que le pasas a `printf()` no es el contenido de la memoria apuntada por `p`, sino el propio valor de `p`, es decir, la dirección a la que apunta. Debido al `"%d"` esa dirección se mostrará como un número decimal. Si hubieras usado en cambio `"%p"` te lo habría mostrado en hexadecimal (ya que `%p` es para mostrar direcciones de memoria, que suelen escribirse en hexadecimal)

### Tercero ¿por qué tampoco rompe este caso?

```
printf("%s", ((char *)p));
```

En este caso le dices al compilador "Considera temporalmente que `p` es un puntero a `char`". Supongamos que el puntero sigue apuntando al mismo lugar que apuntaba en el ejemplo anterior, en el cual hay cuatro bytes: `2c`, `ff`, `28` y `00`. No obstante lo que estás pasando a `printf()` no son esos bytes, sino la dirección en la que se hallan.

Como cadena de formato usas `"%s"`. Esta cadena le dice a `printf()` que el siguiente parámetro será una dirección de memoria en la que, supuestamente, hay una cadena. Las cadenas no son más que secuencias de bytes terminadas con un cero, luego en cierto sentido es verdad que la secuencia `2c`, `ff`, `28` y `00` es una cadena.

`printf()` irá a la dirección de memoria indicada, leerá el primer byte (`2c`) y mostrará por la terminal la letra cuyo código ASCII es `2c`, que es la coma. Y después leerá el siguiente, que es `ff` y mostrará la letra con ese ASCII. En este caso no hay ASCII con ese valor, por lo que lo que muestre dependerá de la codificación de la terminal. Por ejemplo, si usas codificación `latin1` mostrará una `ÿ`. Y seguirá avanzando por posiciones de memoria y mostrándolas como caracteres, hasta encontrar un 0 que le indica que la cadena ha terminado. En nuestro caso encontrará un `28` (código ASCII del paréntesis), y finalmente el 0 que le hará parar.

Por tanto en la pantalla podrías ver algo como: `,ÿ(`

### Cuarto. Ok, entonces ¿por qué rompe este caso?

Si añades un asterisco delante del casting, rompe. Es decir, así:

```
printf("%s", *((char *)p));
```

En este caso el `(char *)p`, al igual que antes, le dice al compilador "considera momentánamente que `p` es un puntero a `char`". Después, el asterisco adicional le dice "accede a la dirección a que apunta `p` y dame el dato", pero ya que antes dijimos que `p` apuntaba a `char`, esta vez se leerá sólo un byte de la memoria, en lugar de 4 como ocurrió cuando `p` se consideró `(int*)`.

Es decir, `*((char*)p)` nos da ahora el primer byte al que apunta `p`.

Si seguimos suponiendo que `p` apuntaba a una zona donde había una secuencia `2c`, `ff`, `28` y `00` , la expresión `*((char*)p)` daría como resultado `2c` (que en decimal es 44). Y ese es el valor que estás pasando como segundo parámetro a `printf()`. Un byte con el valor 44.

**Pero** (y esta es la clave) lo que `printf()` estaba esperando era una dirección de memoria **debido a que** habías usado `"%s"` como cadena de formato. Como vimos en el apartado anterior, `printf()` espera la dirección donde haya una cadena (secuencia de bytes terminada en 0), pero ahora le estás pasando en cambio el número 44.

Lo que hará `printf()`, obediente, es acceder a la dirección de memoria `44` para leer el byte que allí haya y mostrarlo como carácter. **Y aquí es donde romperá**, porque la dirección de memoria `44` está protegida contra lectura (como cualquier dirección de memoria baja, pues las únicas de las que podremos leer son las que pertenecen a nuestro proceso, el cual es cargado normalmente en direcciones altas de memoria).

Comment: gracias amigo, esto responde a la pregunta, aunque aún no estoy familiarizado con "memoria alta/baja". 
Salu2!

Answer (score 0):

Esos numeros como te comentaron son los cuatro bytes de p como int, si quieres saber la direccion de memoria tendrias que poner en `printf ("%p", p)`, que se refiere a un puntero.
Cuando pones *p te sale el primer elemento porque es equivalente a p[0] (en terminos de punteros), si colocas `*(p+1)` podras notar mas facilmente porque te dara el siguiente numero. No se si eso responde a tu pregunta, solo respondi LA CUESTION, lo primero que escribiste no es muy claro